# How can I get and store Data from Textfield in Form Container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, twilio

I have this code below for a webtool to edit Twilio Queue information, I am having issues with passing data upwards from the different forms, how can I return or store the data to the Save (activated when I click the save button) function from the text fields with the following IDs (cap_percent_threshold, abandoned_target_threshold, asa_threshold, abandoned_percent_threshold).

```
import React, { useRef, Component } from 'react'
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import axios from 'axios';

function FormRow(data) {
    const queue = data.data;
    const channels = queue.channels;
    const tresholdData = {};

    console.log('threshold data', tresholdData);

    return (
        channels.map((channel, index) => (<Grid container item sm={12} spacing={3} >
            <Grid item sm={2} >
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="channel_name"
                    label="Channel"
                    type="text"
                    value={channel.friendly_name}
                    fullWidth
                    disabled
                />
            </Grid >


            <Grid item sm={2} >
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="cap_percent_threshold"
                    label="Cap Percent Threshold"
                    value={channel.capPercentThreshold}
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                />
            </Grid >
            <Grid item sm={2} >
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="abandoned_target_threshold"
                    label="Abandoned Target Threshold"
                    value={channel.abandonedTargetThreshold}
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                />
            </Grid >
            <Grid item sm={2} >
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="asa_threshold"
                    label="ASA Threshold"
                    value={channel.aSAThreshold}
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth

                />
            </Grid >
            <Grid item sm={2} >
                <TextField
                    autoFocus
                    margin="dense"
                    id="abandoned_percent_threshold"
                    label="Abandoned Percent Threshold"
                    value={channel.abandonedPercentThreshold}
                    onChage={input => tresholdData += input}
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                />
            </Grid >
        </Grid >

            
        ))
    );
}

function FormContainer(data) {
    console.log('what');
    console.log(data);
    const queue = data;

    const cancel = () => {
        console.log('cancel');
    }

    const save = (event) => {



        console.log('save');
        console.log(': ', event);
        console.log('Data on save: ', data);

        const postURL = `https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/${workspaceSid}/TaskQueues/${testTaskQueue}`

        /*

        const updateTaskQueuePromise = axios.post(postURL, {
            apiKey: this.props.credentials().apiKey,
            apiSecret: this.props.credentials().apiSecret,

        }).then(result => {
            console.log('Result from Save Axios: ', result)

        }
        */



    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container >
                <Grid item sm={1} ></Grid >
                <Grid container item sm={11} spacing={3} >
                    <FormRow data={queue} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid container
                    direction="row"
                    justify="flexend"
                    alignItems="center">
                    <Grid item sm={1} ></Grid >
                    <Grid item sm={11} spacing={3} justify="flexend" alignItems="center" >
                        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={cancel} color="secondary" > Cancel</Button >
                        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={save} color="primary" > Save</Button >
                    </Grid >
                </Grid >
            </Grid >
        </div >
    );
}

export default class Editor extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        /*
            _handleTextFieldChange: function (e) {
                this.setState({
                    textFieldValue: e.target.value
                });
    
                */

        this.state = {
            open: false,
            queue: {},
            columns: [
                { title: 'Queue Name', field: 'friendly_name', editable: 'never' },
                { title: 'Channel', field: 'channel_friendly_name', editable: 'never' },
                { title: 'Cap Percent Threshold', field: 'capPercentThreshold', type: 'numeric' },
                { title: 'Abandoned Target Threshold', field: 'abandonedTargetThreshold', type: 'numeric' },
                { title: 'ASA Threshold', field: 'aSAThreshold', type: 'numeric' },
                { title: 'Abondended Percent Threshold', field: 'abandonedPercentThreshold', type: 'numeric' }
                //{ title: 'Reset Timezone', field: 'channel_reset_timezone' },
                //{ title: 'Reset Time', field: 'channel_reset_time' },
                // { title: 'Service Level Threshold', field: 'channel_service_level_threshold', type: 'numeric' },
                //{ title: 'Short Abandoned Threshold', field: 'channel_service_level_threshold', type: 'numeric' },
                //Added to Edit the color Changing Thresholds

            ]
        }
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);




    }

    handleClose(xxx) {
        console.log('this happening');
        console.log(xxx);
        this.setState({ open: true });
    }


    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ textFieldValue: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('An essay was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    render() {
        console.log('Render this props.data!!');
        console.group(this.props.data);
        const queues = this.props.data.map(q => {
            const channel = q.channels.find(c => c.unique_name === 'voice');
            q.channel_friendly_name = channel.friendly_name;
            q.channel_reset_time = channel.reset_time;
            //q.channel_reset_timezone = channel.reset_timezone;
            //q.channel_service_level_threshold = channel.service_level_threshold;
            //Added To Edit the Color Changing Thresholds:
            q.channel_service_level_threshold = channel.capPercentThreshold;
            q.channel_service_level_threshold = channel.abandonedTargetThreshold;
            q.channel_service_level_threshold = channel.aSAThreshold;
            q.channel_service_level_threshold = channel.abandonedPercentThreshold;

            return q;
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <MaterialTable
                    title='Queue SLA'
                    columns={this.state.columns}
                    data={queues}
                    options={
                        {
                            pageSize: 25,
                            pageSizeOptions: [25, 100, 500, 1000]
                        }
                    }
                    detailPanel={
                        rowData => {
                            return FormContainer(rowData);
                        }
                    }
                />
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When you click save do you expect to save the updates to all the queues?

Comment: Not all queues, just the single queue that is currently opened. But I cant manage to get any data from the FormRow container back to the FormContainer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant channels, not queues. There are multiple channels showing here and one save button should update them all?

Comment: Yes, the original idea was once the save button it is clicked the data from all the channels fields should be stored and saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The structure of your form and the data within it seem relatively arbitrary. I know it is based on whatever data that you get from the TaskRouter API, which will likely not change, but you do still have to render lists of form items. To that end I wrote up a quick experiment to see how you could solve this for any object that you can give a component. Hopefully this is helpful and you can apply it to your application.

---

React's model is that data is sent down and actions bubble up, so in this case you want to store your form's state in the top level component, which also handles the form's submit event, and send that state down to the child components. The child components should then send up change events that update the state.

Then, when the form is submitted, you can send the full state to the endpoint *(side note here, we recommend that you implement calls to the Twilio API on the server side, not in the client, so that you don't embed your API credentials in the front-end where they can be taken)*. I note that your application doesn't currently have a `<form>` element (that I can see), I do recommend you wrap form elements in a `<form>` so that you can handle the submission of the `<form>` with an `onSubmit` handler.

The previous paragraph is the easy part, the harder part is keeping the state up to date. If you run your code as you have it, where a number of the inputs have a `value` attribute but not an `onChange` handler, you'll find React telling you that you need to do something about it.

So, you need to implement an `onChange` handler that updates the state in the top level component. I had a go at implementing this myself, for an arbitrary object full of data. I created a `handleUpdate` function that could be passed to any input as an `onChange` handler. When the `handleUpdate` function is triggered, it is passed an event which points to the DOM element that triggered it. You can use this to get the value of the element to update your state:

```js
const handleUpdate = (event) => {
  const element = event.target;
  const value = element.value;
  console.log(value);
  // we'll come back to this
}
```

Now we have the value we just need to update the state. To do so, we need to know where in the state the original value was, and replace it. I handled this in my experiment by building up a string made up of the keys you need to traverse the object and writing a function that would clone the original state, unpick the keys and update the value before returning what could be set as the new state. That function looks like this:

```js
function updateObject(obj, keys, value) {
  // deep copy the state object
  obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  let innerObj = obj;
  // Follow the keys to the value that needs to be updated
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
    innerObj = innerObj[keys[i]];
  }
  // Update the value
  innerObj[keys[i]] = value;
  // Return the new state object
  return obj;
}
```

So, if you have a state object that looked like this:

```js
const state = { "foo": { "bar": "baz" } };
```

And you ran the above function like this:

```js
updateObject(state, "foo.bar", "qux");
// => { "foo": { "bar": "qux" }}
```

This works with arrays too, since the index of an array are just string keys into an object:

```js
const state = { "foo": [{ "bar": "baz" }] };
updateObject(state, "foo.0.bar", "qux");
// => { "foo": [{ "bar": "qux" }]}
```

With the `updateObject` function, we can now update any value in our state as long as we have the path to that object. In your case, you might be able to achieve this in an easier manner, but in my experiment I built up the path as I recursively traversed the state object, passing down the `handleUpdate` function and eventually made the path the `name` attribute on my input elements. (That built up path string was also useful as a `key` attribute for React.)

The `handleUpdate` function itself became:

```js
const handleUpdate = (event) => {
  // Find the keys of the object that lead to the value that needs to be changed
  const path = event.target.name;
  const keys = path.split(".");
  // Update the state
  setData(updateObject(data, keys, event.target.value));
};
```

Overall, I created two components, an outer `<Form>` component, that controlled the state and created the event handlers for `onChange` and `onSubmit` events, and a `<FormRow>` that recursively rendered the data in the state. Here are those two components:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function FormRow({ path, value, handleUpdate, label }) {
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    // If the value is a string, render a label and input
    return (
      <div key={path}>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleUpdate}
          name={path}
        ></input>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    // Otherwise, assume the value is an array and render a new FormRow for each
    // item in the array
    return value.map((obj, i) => {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            marginLeft: "10px",
            borderLeft: "2px solid #000",
          }}
          key={`${path}-${i}`}
        >
          {Object.keys(obj).map((key) => (
            <FormRow
              key={`${path}.${i}.${key}`}
              // We construct a path here that is a map of keys/indices to the
              // value from the root of the original object
              path={`${path}.${i}.${key}`}
              value={obj[key]}
              handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
              label={key}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
}

function Form({ startingData }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(startingData);

  function updateObject(obj, keys, value) {
    // deep copy the state object
    obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    let innerObj = obj;
    // Follow the keys to the value that needs to be updated
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
      innerObj = innerObj[keys[i]];
    }
    // Update the value
    innerObj[keys[i]] = value;
    // Return the new state object
    return obj;
  }

  const handleUpdate = (event) => {
    // Find the keys of the object that lead to the value that needs to be changed
    const path = event.target.name;
    const keys = path.split(".");
    // Update the state
    setData(updateObject(data, keys, event.target.value));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Data submitted: ", data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key, i) => (
        <FormRow
          key={`${key}-${i}`}
          path={key}
          value={data[key]}
          handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
          label={key}
        />
      ))}

      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

You can then render the `<Form>` component, passing it a `startingData` prop, and it will render the entire form needed and the handlers for submitting it.

Ultimately, for your implementation, you might be able to keep your existing structure and implement a similar `handleUpdate` function in your `<FormContainer>` element and render each of the `<TextField>`s with a `name` prop that can direct to the original value in the state and the `handleUpdate` function.

Something like:

```js
return (
  channels.map((channel, index) => (<Grid container item sm={12} spacing={3} >
    <Grid item sm={2} >
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin="dense"
        id="channel_name"
        label="Channel"
        type="text"
        fullWidth
        disabled
        value={channel.friendly_name}
        onChange={handleUpdate}
        name={`data.channels.${index}.friendly_name`}
      />
    </Grid >

   // more Grid items
```

Then the `<FormContainer>` might look like this (I added a `<form>`, created a `handleUpdate` function and passed it down to the `FormRow`):

```js
function FormContainer(data) {
  const [queue, setQueue] = useState(data);
  
  const cancel = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("cancel");
  };

  const save = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // save the data in the state
  };

  const updateObject = (obj, keys, value) => {
    obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    let innerObj = obj;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
      innerObj = innerObj[keys[i]];
    }
    innerObj[keys[i]] = value;
    return obj;
  }
  
  const handleUpdate = (event) => {
    const path = event.target.name;
    const keys = path.split(".");
    setQueue(updateObject(queue, keys, event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={save}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item sm={1}></Grid>
        <Grid container item sm={11} spacing={3}>
          <FormRow data={queue} handleUpdate={handleUpdate} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container direction="row" justify="flexend" alignItems="center">
          <Grid item sm={1}></Grid>
          <Grid item sm={11} spacing={3} justify="flexend" alignItems="center">
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={cancel} color="secondary">
              {" "}
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">
              {" "}
              Save
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Wow, this is a long answer! I hope you made it this far, please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added the handleChange function and added the useState to the FormContainer but get the following error :

> 107 |    const [queue, setQueue] = useState(data);

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Your `FormContainer` is a function component (at least, in your question's code), have you changed it to a class based component? Or, have you put the `useState` in a loop or conditional somewhere?

Comment: I finally got it working by adding props to the FormRow functions and using onChange={props.handleChange} and adding the handle change function you provided. Thank you so much for all your help!.

Comment: So glad it helped!